# Correctly accessing Core Data from another thread using the new Asynchronous Task in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous, core-data

To test my Core Data implementation I have enabled the launch argument `com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1`. I am getting breakpoints triggered whenever I access a managed object from within a `Task` using Swifts new async APIs.

I use a single context (`viewContext`) for fetching and ephemeral background contexts to perform write operations. See some snippets of the important parts at the bottom.

My app functions perfectly and I get no breakpoints triggered except for the scenarios where I access a Core Data managed object from within a `Task`.

See an example here

```
func performReloadForecasts() {
    Task {
        await reloadForecasts()
    }
}
```

The method `reloadForecasts` is too long to post here but it references the users favourite location (Hence the `locations`) and uses it to fetch the forecast from an API for that location.
Referencing the users locations in views or view models functions fine.

But from what I can tell, by using a `Task` to perform an asynchronous operation, I am performing the task in a whole different thread that is chosen (from a pool?) at run time.

Usually the thread that the `Task` is run in is `com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos.cooperative (serial)` which makes sense I suppose.

How can I refactor or change either my asynchronous functions (such as `reloadForecast`) or my core data stack (detailed below) to perform operations in a manor that abides by the concurrency rules for Core Data?

Can I force a Task to run on a particular thread? Since my main context is the `viewContext` it would have to be the main thread, which sort of defeats the purpose of the async `Task`.

Can I refactor my core data stack to create some sort of thread safe reference to my managed objects? I have seen suggestions to pass object ID's in and refetch the object inside the target thread but surely there is a more elegant way to abide by the concurrency rules.

### **Core Data Implementation**

**Context Setup**

```
container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Model")

context = container.viewContext
context.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
```

**Fetching**

```
@Published private var locations: [LocationModel] = []
```

```
private func reloadData() {
    context.perform { [context] in
        do {
            self.locations = try context.fetch(LocationModel.fetchRequest())
        } catch {
            Logger.error("Failed to reload persistence layer.")
            Logger.error(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

**Performing Write Operations**

```
func perform(_ block: @escaping (NSManagedObjectContext) -> Void) {
    do {
        let context = container.newBackgroundContext()

        try context.performAndWait {
            block(context)
            try context.save()
        }
    } catch {
        Logger.error(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Each time you access or write a value of a `NSManagedObject`, you should do it in its designated queue, with for instance a `context.perform{}` or `context.perfomAndWait{}`. You can retrieve the `managedObject.managedObjectContext` if needed, or if you already know the context, use a reference on it, and keep it. Exception is done with viewContext, which is main thread, so in this particular case `DispatchQueue.main.async` works (until you change your code). You can also retrieve with `objectID` instance from other context threads (there is limit if modified)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I make sure to only read core data objects from its designated context. I use the `viewContext` to fetch items but when I then attempt to access a list of objects (see the `@Published` variable `locations`) it is sometimes done in the incorrect thread. 

When I reference the objects from a view things work fine (Because views are limited to the main thread). 
But if I am referencing an object from another class, particularly within async `Task`s I get breakpoints triggered.

How can I ensure my `Task`s use the correct thread when accessing objects?

Comment: I think you should use actors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed some of these issues by adding the `@MainActor` flag to the `Task`

```
    Task { @MainActor in
        await reloadForecasts()
    }
```

However I was still getting breakpoints for certain issues, especially higher order functions like maps or sorts. I ended up adding the `@MainActor` wrapper to all my view models.

This fixed all of the weird crashes regarding the higher order functions accessing the core data objects, but I faced new problems. My second core data context used for saving objects was now the cause of concurrency breakpoints being triggered.

This made more sense and was much more debug-able. I had strong references to objects fetched in the main context, used to construct another object in the background context.

`Model A <---> Model B`

I had `Model A` that had relationship to another `Model B`. To setup the relationship to `Model B`, I used a reference to a `Model B` object that had been fetched on the main context. But I was creating the `Model A` object in the background thread.

To solve this I used the suggested methods of refetching the required objects by ObjectID in the correct context. (Using a bunch of nice helper methods to make things easier)

Here's a forum post asking a related question about ensuring asynchronous tasks are run on the main thread

https://forums.swift.org/t/best-way-to-run-an-anonymous-function-on-the-main-actor/50083

My understanding of the new swift concurrency models is that when you `await` on an async function, the task is run on another thread chosen from a pool and when the task is complete, execution returns to the point (and thread) you used `await`.

In this case I have forced the Task to start on the main thread (By using @MainActor), execute its task on a thread from the available pool, and return back to the main thread once its completed.

The swift concurrency explains some of this in detail: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html